# Why the following system of congruences is guaranteed to have a unique solution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have encountered the following problem in Durrett:

$X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on $\{0, \dots, K-1\}$ where $K$ is a prime. Let $Z_n = X+nY $ mod $K$ where $0\leq n < K$. I need to show that $Z_0, \dots, Z_{K-1}$ are pairwise indpendent. Now I need to consider the following system of congruences,
$$
Z_n = i,
$$
$$
Z_m = j,
$$
where $n > m$ and $0 \leq i,j < K$. This is equivalent to
$$
X = i - \frac{n(i-j)}{n-m} (\text{mod } K),
$$
$$
Y = \frac{i-j}{n-m} (\text{mod } K).
$$
Since the remainder term in the above can certainly be fractions, how do I show the above solution actually exists in $\{0,\dots, K-1\}$ and is unique? There does seem to be many sources online that suggests this is always true but I can't find any detailed proof of it. I also don't think I can directly quote some theorem. Can anyone provide some hint? Thank you!

Comment: If $0\le m<n<K$ with $K$ prime, then $n-m$ is relatively prime to $K$ and therefore invertible mod $K$ (cf. [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity))